# IHttpModule filter write method is not called asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jsonp, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to change the response to get jsonp(for web services), but the problem is that the write method is never ever called only flush() is called at the end, the url is 
localhost:8080/api/employees

its calling web api  and employee is a controller file,

Controller Method which is called

```
public List<Models.Employee> Get() {

            var employees = from e in _context.Employees
                            select new Models.Employee {
                                Id = e.EmployeeID,
                                FirstName = e.FirstName,
                                LastName = e.LastName
                            };


            return employees.ToList();

}
```

IHTTPModule Method which is invoked

```
public void OnReleaseRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            if (response.ContentType != JSON_CONTENT_TYPE && response.ContentType != JSON_CONTENT_TYPE1) return;

            //response.ContentEncoding =
           // char[] c = { 'd', 's', 'w', 'w' };

            response.Filter = new JsonResponseFilter(response.Filter);
            //response.Cache.
           // response.ClearContent();
           // response.Write(c, 0, 4);
           // response.Flush();
        }
```

Now JsonResponseFilter.write is not called thats the issue, anyone kindly reply back to resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it all wrong. Don't use any IHttpModules. The correct way to achieve this in the Web API is to use a custom [media formatter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters). For example there's a [JsonpFormatter](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.Web.Http/blob/master/Thinktecture.Web.Http/Formatters/JsonpFormatter.cs) that you could integrate in `Application_Start` and which will enable JSONP for your web methods:

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter());
```